# Can I skip constants in this limit?

Tags: limits

It would help me a lot, since L'Hospital would be very fast in that case. The [Limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8jAH.png) is approaching infinity and numbers 1 and -1 do not seem to be too significant. Would it be legit move? Or is there any smarter way to solve this limit?

Comment: the limit is not approaching anything. it either exists or it doesn't

Comment: (a) Yes, you can; (b) L'Hopital is **really** overkill here. Do you know how to prove $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^2} = 1,$$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4x^2}{4x^2-1} = 1,$$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{x^2}}{4x^2} = \frac{1}{4}$$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Set $1/x=h\implies h\to0^+$

$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{h^2+1}}{|h|}$

And for $h>0,|h|=+h$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{4x^2-1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}}{4-1/x^2} = \frac14 $$

Comment: Given the question, it does seem that the OP needs a lot more pedagogy than this. You basically sweep under the rug, in your last equality, the core confusion the OP is having.

Comment: @ClementC. Point taken.  But there is a difference between OP's question and my last equality.  I'm discarding infinitesimal quantities while OP's question is about discarding finite quantities (against a infinity, nevertheless).  I was hoping the former is a bit easier to be accepted by OP.

Comment: @Guangliang Could you please explain how exactly was the second limit made? I don't seem be intuitively able to figure out.

Comment: @JohnSmith Divide both the numerator and denominator by $x^2$.

Comment: projectilemotion Dumb me, thanks.